# Handling Exceptions in Scala FS2 Stream Transformation flow

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect, fs2

```scala
import cats.effect.{IO, IOApp}
import fs2.Pipe
import fs2.Stream

object Test extends IOApp.Simple {

  final case class Student(id: Int, name: String)

  private val studentData: Map[Int, Student] = Map(1 -> Student(1, "Olivia"), 2 -> Student(2, "Liam"))

  override def run: IO[Unit] = {

    def firstTransformation: Pipe[IO, Int, Student] = {
      stream =>
        stream.evalMap(id => IO(studentData(id))) // Here database or an external API call is performed.
    }

    def secondTransformation: Pipe[IO, Student, String] = {
      stream =>
        stream.evalMap(student => IO(student.name)) // Here database or an external API call is performed.
    }

    val sourceStream: Stream[IO, Int] = Stream(1, 2, 3).repeat

    sourceStream
      .through(firstTransformation)
      .through(secondTransformation)
      .map(name => println(s"name $name"))
      .compile
      .drain
  }
}
```

How can exceptions in FS2 stream transformations be handled to ensure uninterrupted flow even if an exception occurs midway through a transformation?
In the current setup the stream should indefinitely print only "Olivia" and "Liam" despite any exceptions.

It should output:
name Olivia
name Liam
name Olivia
name Liam
name Olivia
name Liam
.........
.........
infinitely

**How can we design our stream flow and manage exceptions to ensure that it doesn't halt the FS2 flow? Thank you in advance.**

Comment: I might write a detailed answer later but TLDR don't use Pipe like that, it's horrible for building an interface around, instead use functions like `A => B` or `A => F[B]` or `A => Stream[B]`. Any time you have some pipe `= _.streamMethod(blah)`, don't do that, instead just expose `blah`

Comment: @Daenyth please suggest detailed answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: add proper handling for errors in your transformation steps.

Also: I agree with @Daenyth about how to represent your transformation functions. You should generally follow the principle of least power; if your transformation is just a simple function, then represent it as a simple function and not some complex wrapper type. This allows your function to be called more flexibly in different situations.

```scala
// return None instead of throwing if the student doesn't exist
def lookupStudent(id: Int): IO[Option[Student]]

def getStudentName(student: Student): IO[String]
```

In the above, the `lookupStudent` step accounts for the possibility of a "no such student" outcome as part of the return type, instead of as a thrown exception.

In both steps, you said that an API call or DB lookup might happen. Since these could fail in unforeseen ways, you need to decide what should happen in those situations. You *could* catch the error and return a `None`, effectively swallowing the error. I don't generally recommend doing that, but hey, it's your program.

```scala
def lookupStudentResiliently(id: Int): IO[Option[Student]] = 
  lookupStudent(id).recover {
    case e: Exception => None
  }

def getStudentNameResiliently(student: Student): IO[Option[String]] =
  getStudentName(student).redeem[Option[String]](
    thrownException => None,
    name => Some(name)
  )
```

The above `*Resiliently` functions will catch errors raised by the underlying `lookupStudent / getStudentName` IOs and treat them as if the lookup just returned a `None`.

Then you can incorporate these lookups into your stream using any of the various `fs2.Stream` composition methods. I'll use `evalMapFilter` in my example since fits the desired(?) semantics of "just skip it if it doesn't work", when "it doesn't work" is represented by one of the transformations returning a `None`.

```scala
sourceStream
  .evalMapFilter(lookupStudentResiliently) // changed
  .evalMapFilter(getStudentNameResiliently) // changed
  .map(name => println(s"name $name"))
  .compile
  .drain
```